# CTE and @table in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **CTE** and a **@table** variable

```
WITH source AS (.......)

declare @fsijActiveFunds table (.......)
insert into @fsijActiveFunds exec MyDB.dbo.sp_FSIJ_GetActiveFunds '20190930'

SELECT
something

FROM
source

WHERE source.isin not in (SELECT SMF_ISIN from @fsijActiveFunds)
```

I am somehow stuck with

> incorrect syntax near declare

error, because I work in a stone age **MS Query** and **PSPad**.
I know that both the **CTE** and **@table** work well independently, but not together in the same query. :)

Am I missing a comma, semicolon?? Any thoughts??
Thanks in advance

Comment: The Cte belongs to the SELECT, not to declare.

Comment: declare before cte

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table declaration goes *before* the query:

```
declare @fsijActiveFunds table (.......)
    insert into @fsijActiveFunds
        exec MyDB.dbo.sp_FSIJ_GetActiveFunds '20190930';

WITH source AS (.......)
SELECT something
FROM source
WHERE source.isin not in (SELECT SMF_ISIN from @fsijActiveFunds);
```

Note that it does have to be in the same "programming block".  That is, you cannot put a `GO` in between, because the scope of the variable ends, and subsequent code will no longer see the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I had the declaration before the query (before I started fiddling with the code), but was missing the semicolon ... I think I should have a closer look at its role to learn something new.

Comment: @Reeve . . . The semicolon is actually needed for the `with` -- otherwise it is not properly recognized as a CTE.  I habitually end statements with a semi-colon anyway, so that always works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No - the semi-colon is NOT needed with the with. The statement prior to the CTE must be terminated. And a general best practice is to terminate all statements. You know better - that was a lousy comment.